# SQl server denali installation

Tags: sql-server

Installation of SQL server Denali (2011) CTP upgrades the BIDS 2008.
Is there any way possible that this does not happens as this I am using BIDS 2008 for creating SSIS packages for SQL server 2008 .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You really really don't want to be installing a CTP release on a machine/server that you use for any other purpose, for the simple reason alone that it is a CTP release, unless of course you are happy with the fact that you may need to rebuild the machine at some point.

My advice, get either a dedicated server for testing Denali or setup a Virtual Machine to do so.

Comment: Hi John,


Alas I am writing new answer because I am not able to see comment link under you answer. My question is can you recommend any Virtual Machine that I can use for my Mindows XP system?

Comment: You can use VMWare Player